# Insert statement does not work (even in the copied db at Documents folder)

Tags: ios, sqlite

First of all I'm new here, so i would like to thank the community which is helping me a lot in my projects.

I'm actually working on an application which have to provide customers information from local sqlite db.

I did the following :

- I copy the sqlite database (if no db exist in document folder) when the application is launched
- When the user is asking for update in the interface, a method is called and fill the customer_information table in the database.
- When the user is going back to the main screen, a method is called and refresh information displaying according to values in the sqlite database.

The problem is that no values are displaying. XCode can't found any errors in my code and even if I tried many different way for inserting values, I can't find where is the issue.

Thank you in advance and sorry about my bad english, I'm French.

Sincerely.

Please find following extracts from my source code, you have any question don't hesitate :

*Copying the db in documents folder*

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSError *emsg;
    BOOL fileExist;

    //Get list of directories in Document path
    NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    //Define new path for database
    NSString *documentPath = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Vidagen_ios.sqlite"];

    // Path of db in the application
    NSString *origin = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Vidagen_ios.sqlite"];

    fileExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentPath];

    if(!fileExist){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:origin toPath:documentPath error:&emsg];
        NSLog(@"db copied");
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

*Update method*

```
- (void)insertRecords
{
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement = nil;
    sqlite3 *newDb;

    // Request
    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO client_information(client_info_id, client_info_name, client_info_sex, client_info_age, client_info_id_card, client_info_tel, client_info_tall, client_info_weight, client_info_address, client_info_email, client_info_pwd, client_info_client_source_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    // Path of copied db
    NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *database = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Vidagen_ios.sqlite"];

    // db sequence
    if(sqlite3_open([database UTF8String], &newDb) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"ouverture de la base ok");
        for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, i, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, 11, 1);
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(newDb, sql, 1, &sqlStatement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"client ajouté");
        } else{
            NSLog(@"Echec d'ajout");
        }
        sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_close(newDb);
    };

}
```

Here's i noticed that the step is different than "SQLITE_OK".

*Method displaying the information*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    infoCustomer = [[CustomerDAO alloc] init];
    if([[infoCustomer getCurrentCustomer] count] > 0){
        self.customer = [[infoCustomer getCurrentCustomer] objectAtIndex:0];

        [self.uniqueId setText:self.customer.uniqueId];
        [self.name setText:self.customer.name];
        [self.sex setText:self.customer.sex];
        [self.tall setText:self.customer.tall];
        [self.weight setText:self.customer.weight];
        [self.age setText:self.customer.age];
        [self.address setText:self.customer.address];
        [self.tel setText:self.customer.tel];
        [self.email setText:self.customer.email];
    } else{
        NSLog(@"customer not read");
        [self.uniqueId setText:@"Go to Update."];
        [self.name setText:@""];
        [self.sex setText:@""];
        [self.tall setText:@""];
        [self.weight setText:@""];
        [self.age setText:@""];
        [self.address setText:@""];
        [self.tel setText:@""];
        [self.email setText:@""];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

> ***EDIT :***
>
> I continued my research since yesterday and though something wrong in
>   my source code :
>
> ```
> sqlite3_prepare_v2(newDb, sql, 1, &sqlStatement, NULL);
> ```
>
> The third parameter have to be change to -1 since it's defining the
>   length of my request. I used some tutorials for learning sqlite
>   request and I didn't really spend time to understand all the
>   parameters I saw. If you define it as -1 that's means the length will
>   be auto-calculated at the runtime.
>
> I feel frustrated to loose so many time on such mistake, it shown to
>   me how it is hard to work with no enough experience or no external
>   opinion.

Comment: That shows you how important the documentation is.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html